# Limit as x tends to 0 of $\dfrac{1-\cos(x^5)}{2x^{10}}$

Tags: limits

$$\dfrac{1-\cos(x^5)}{2x^{10}}$$

I used L'Hopital's rule and got $\dfrac{5x^4 \sin(x^5)}{20x^9}$

What can I do from here?

Comment: Cancel common factors, and do a lot more iterations of L'Hospital's rule. Or forget about L'H and just use the Taylor expansion of $\cos$, $$\cos y = 1 - \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^4}{24} + O(y^6).$$ Insert $y = x^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{5x^4 \sin(x^5)}{20x^9}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{5}{20}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(x^5)}{x^5},$$ then use the common limit $\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$.

Comment: I know the answer is 1/4 from 5/20 and you can cancel the $\dfrac{5x^4}{20x^4}$, but then how do you deal with the left over bit?

Comment: @Jim Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** you can simplify the initial limit if you note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^5)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(y)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $~\dfrac{1-\cos t}2=\sin^2\dfrac t2\quad$ and $\quad\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}~\frac{\sin u}u=1$.

Comment: Also, you can simplify things a lot just by letting $y=x^5$.